# Spring boot Authorization server redirection issue to client after successful authentication via Facebook

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth

I am trying to setup a spring boot Authorizaiton server which will have the internal user login and OAuth2 with facebook. I am facing the below issues -

1. If I make my Authorization server SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS then after successful authentication from facebook control get stuck in Authorization server itself (Its not returning to the my client application while if SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED then control returns to my client app).
2. When I am using SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED then control returns and I can do a authorization_code flow but the jwt token generated by spring-security-jwt gives me only user_name information in token which is facebook user's id (not even name).
3. My local user authentication code works fine with code flow and I can customize my token with custom token enhancer and add other properties also but when I try to customize facebook principal object to my custom user I get error that string can not be casted to custom user object.

Please refer to the repo for details - [dev repo](https://github.com/eliteofindia/zdesk/tree/development/oauth2)

I am using below code for setup/jwt generation -

```
@EnableOAuth2Client // for Oauth setup

// jwt enhancer which gives me error when principal is converted to custom user 
class CustomTokenEnhancer implements TokenEnhancer {
    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        Map<String, Object> additionalInfo = new HashMap<>();
        Authentication auth = authentication.getUserAuthentication();
       /* additionalInfo.put("email", ((CustomPrincipal)auth.getPrincipal()).getEmail());
        additionalInfo.put("roles", ((CustomPrincipal)auth.getPrincipal()).getRoles());
        additionalInfo.put("id", ((CustomPrincipal)auth.getPrincipal()).getId());*/
        ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken).setAdditionalInformation(additionalInfo);
        return accessToken;
    }
}
```

//SSO filter i am using -

```
private Filter ssoFilter(ClientResources client, String path) {

    
    OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(path);
    OAuth2RestTemplate template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(client.getClient(), oauth2ClientContext);
    filter.setRestTemplate(template);
    UserInfoTokenServices tokenServices = new UserInfoTokenServices(
            client.getResource().getUserInfoUri(), client.getClient().getClientId());
    tokenServices.setRestTemplate(template);
    filter.setTokenServices(tokenServices);
    // filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(authenticationHandler);
    return filter;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Incase someone came here looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57557022/1581226)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get an explanation for 2nd and 3rd point-

Since after the authentication is successful from Facebook; Spring boot authorization server stores authentication object as below format -

```
 {
"authorities": [
  {
    "authority": "ROLE_USER"
  }
],
"details": {
  "remoteAddress": "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1",
  "sessionId": "xyzxyzxyzxyzxyz",
  "tokenValue": "xyzxyzxyzxyzxyz",
  "tokenType": "bearer",
  "decodedDetails": null
},
"authenticated": true,
"userAuthentication": {
  "authorities": [
    {
      "authority": "ROLE_USER"
    }
  ],
  "details": {
    "id": "xyzxyzxyzxyzxyz",
    "name": "xyzxyzxyzxyzxyz",
    "email": "xyzxyzxyzxyzxyz"
  },
  "authenticated": true,
  "principal": "xyzxyzxyzxyzxyz",
  "credentials": "N/A",
  "name": "xyzxyzxyzxyzxyz"
},
"principal": "xyzxyzxyzxyzxyz",
"oauth2Request": {
  "clientId": "xyzxyzxyzxyzxyz",
  "scope": [],
  "requestParameters": {},
  "resourceIds": [],
  "authorities": [],
  "approved": true,
  "refresh": false,
  "redirectUri": null,
  "responseTypes": [],
  "extensions": {},
  "grantType": null,
  "refreshTokenRequest": null
},
```

so when I was casting my principal to custom principal I was getting the error since in above model principal is just a string.

Note - I still have no idea how i can customize the above authentication object to my customuser object.